# Eclipse Validation error - Platform filter did not match:(&(osgi.ws=win32)(osgi.os=win32)(osgi.arch=x86))

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Hi I am getting this error when I validate my configuration.

Any ideas how to fix this?

here is the error:
Platform filter did not match:(&(osgi.ws=win32)(osgi.os=win32)(osgi.arch=x86))

here is the screeenshot:[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a 32 bit plugin for Windows. It does not match the platform, GUI system or architecture you are trying to use.

Plugins like SWT are platform, GUI and architecture dependent so you need to choose the correct one.

If you are using a target platform with a different settings from your main Eclipse you must make sure the Run Configuration specifies the correct settings.

In the 'Program Arguments' section of the Run Configuration make sure you have:

```
-os ${target.os} -ws ${target.ws} -arch ${target.arch} -nl ${target.nl}
```

You will need to select an appropriate Java JRE (32 bit or 64 bit) as well.

Comment: thanks for reply @greg-449. how do u mean choose the correct one? u mean choose 32 bit version of java?

Comment: Well if you are running 64 bit Mac with Cocoa you need the 64 bit, Mac, Cocoa SWT. If you are running 64 bit Windows you need the 64 bit Windows SWT and so on. Each Platform/GUI/Architecture has a different SWT (and several other plugins).

Comment: thanks fhis, im using 64 bit eclipse and its a lot of work for me to install and setup 32bit eclipse. Im following this guide and will let you know if it helps: http://blog.vogella.com/2016/02/15/run-an-eclipse-32-bit-application-from-a-64-bit-eclipse-ide/

Comment: If you are using a 32 bit target platform you need a Run Configuration that specifies 32 bit as well. Show us the Arguments tab of your Run Configuration. Added something about the settings to the answer.